# Scoring products across all stores

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, scoring

I am trying to score each product based off a couple of features. I was thinking I can use the sales rate(7 days prior) as the target column and predict the sales rate using some ensemble technique and attest the score based off the sales rate value.

I feel there are many other ways to do it, but some guidance here will really be helpful. I am trying to look for a good place to start. Also, maybe if its just scoring, are there other statistical techniques I can use instead of machine learning?

End Goal: Try to attest a score to each product, for example: if target has a total of 10000 products, each of these products should have a score based off the input features.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to represent with your score. Expected sales for a day ? need to replace stocks ?

Comment: So I’m looking to score based off of importance of the product with the sales. To know which of the products have best sales along with other relevant factors.